# What is the name of the pressed brass part in a plug socket?

Tags: mains, plug

I am designing a custom smart plug, and it's required to plug into a UK plug socket, and to expose a UK plug socket. For my first prototypes I dismantled timer sockets to get the brass parts, but now the project is moving towards production, I am trying to source them.

I have found places that supply the brass pins that go into the wall socket, but I can't manage to find a supplier of the folded brass sheet that forms the exposed socket. Can someone please tell me what this is called so I might have some more luck sourcing it?

Alternatively, if this core assembly can be sourced, the name for that would also be great.

I am assuming that they are such a standard part that I won't need to get them made custom.

Comment: Regional terminology may matter a lot, but for the US version I had some results searching for "NEMA Blades" in particular finding things from a company called Heyco.  But the challenge is not only finding the contacts, but designing a secure means of anchoring them - and doubly so at prototype volume.  Ultimately it became a non-issue as changing requirements pushed that project away from a plug form factor to one of a box with an external supply adapter.

Answer (score 1):

There are many names for such elements: brass contacts, female connectors, female terminators, power plug connectors, electrical contact connectors etc.

Plenty of these connectors, in various types and sizes You could find in Heyco: https://www.heyco.com/Power_Components/ Of course there are many other manufacturers of such elements, feed the Google with phrases like "power plug/contact/socket brass elements".

Another (in my opinion easier) option is to use complete PCB mounted power socket, like this one:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, for the project I was working on I used a panel mounted socket (https://www.aliexpress.com/item/DIY-Socket-Function-Key-Module-UK-Standard-Electrical-Outlet-Grounded-AC-110-250V/32805344699.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.ADNPTe) but I'd love to know where to order the contacts in this image http://www.cnx-software.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Orvibo_Wiwo_S20_Hardware_Power.jpg

Answer (score 0):

If you mean this: http://www.worldstandards.eu/electricity/plugs-and-sockets/g/ they are called prongs.

The Plug has Pins and the Pins go into Prongs (like prongs on a Fork, no one says "pins on a fork").

Another word used on the Wikipedia Website https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power_plugs_and_sockets:_British_and_related_types#BS_1363-2_13.C2.A0A_switched_and_unswitched_socket-outlets and BS 1363 http://electrical.theiet.org/wiring-matters/49/bs-1363-plug-and-socket.cfm%3Ftype%3Dpdf is "contacts".

Example usage in a sentence: "When looking at the socket with the earth aperture uppermost (as normally mounted) the lower left aperture is for the neutral contact, and the lower right is for the line contact.".

Comment: I mean the counter part to the prongs. I have seen them on a PCB before, but don't know what they're called. Like these:
http://www.cnx-software.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Orvibo_Wiwo_S20_Hardware_Power.jpg

Comment: The BS 1363 (Electrical Standard for Plugs and Sockets) specifies the "Plug" precisely and exactly but the Socket dimensions only require it fit this exactly specified Pin. That lead to (theoretically) no variance between "Plugs" that are 'Standard compliant' but some leeway in the design of the "Socket" so while the Plug only has Pins the Socket is a bit looser in it's specs. Also of interest is that if you can find a Socket Converter or a 'Plug Conversion Cable' it will have both ends and you can cut off the end you don't want; leaving a compatible end and a length of wire. Updated answer.